# How to get values from a C Struct in python?

Tags: c, python-3.x, go

So I created golang code to pass a value to a C struct and then return it into a pointer so that I can get the value in py. But am I able to get the values from the C struct in py? If so, how can I? My main goal is to pass multiple values from go to the C struct then get those values in py. Also what is the right way to do this without any memory leaks?

Heres my go code:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Resp {
    char *response;
    char *responsetwo;
} Resp;

void fill(Resp *r) {
   printf("Original value: %s\n", r->response);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

func body_string(body string, body_two string) unsafe.Pointer {
    sb := C.CString(body)
    sb_two := C.CString(body_two)

    // adding it to the C struct
    return &C.Resp{
        response: sb,
        responsetwo: sb_two,
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but is this okay for large text values? Thank you.

Comment: How do you intend to get it in Python? From memory? From a file?

Comment: No not from a file. From memory.

Comment: each implementation of python provides explanations about how to use its FFI.

Comment: Why on Earth (or in space for that matter) would you use *Go* as an intermediary between C and Python? (Use cpython and the whole problem vanishes.)

Comment: I am trying to pass multiple go values to python through c bindings without any memory leaks.

Comment: How are you combining Go and Python? Are you linking in the Python interpreter? Or are you trying to compile Go as a shared library? I haven't reviewed this blog post, but it might help: https://poweruser.blog/embedding-python-in-go-338c0399f3d5

Comment: I am compiling go as a shared lib.